# Market enabler not working (anymore??)

Tags: google-play-store

I own a MIUI-powered HD2 and a Chinese tablet on which I would like to install a couple of free apps that are intended for Italian market. I can see these apps from an A500 tablet but not from these two devices.

I tried [Market Enabler](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.notenking.mf) (all are already rooted) on both the devices but it seems that it doesn't work. I can still see Chinese apps on the tablet and I'm still on an unknown market from the phone. I would actually like to install Skype on the tablet.

Does somebody know if Android Market now prevents Market enabler to do the trick? I also tried a couple of other enabler apps, but one said that operator change failed.

I understand that my question may look duplicate because lots of people ask how to install other-countries apps, but I'm asking if Google implemented some countermeasures.

Thank you.

[Update] I tried the following

- Clear Market data from Settings\Applications\Manage\All\Market
- Ran Market Enabler, set current market to Italy - TIM (should be 22201), said NO to prompt to switch to market at once. Checked that status bar reported "Current market: Italy"
- Rebooted
- Checked that ME ran on startup by `su` notification
- Started ME, noticed that current market is `Unknown`
- Switched again to Italy from list, chose YES to boot market
- Accepted Android Market license, still saw Chinese apps and no trace of Skype or other apps that I need

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  I wonder if it's something to do with a value in your build.prop file, or perhaps the Market app was modified for China?  What version is the Market?  ( Past comments cleaned :) )

Comment: Market is 2.3.6

Comment: By the way, I'm currently workarounding by downloading apks from several sources, including filestube.com and my tablet using ES File Manager's backup feature

Comment: Ah, definitely try the new Market.  I usually grab 3.4.4 from [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/12/14/download-android-market-3-4-4/), you should just be able to install it over top of the current Market without needing to replace the apk in /system/app.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with US apps once. I wasn't using the same Market Enabler app though.

I use this [Market Enabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler). In most cases, I can get apps just using that, but in some cases, I additionally need to use a proxy, such as [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid).

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a [workaround](https://plus.google.com/110853353138524936530/posts/DqQdqsRbnTE) with this app and the latest version of the Market that may work for you:

> There's a trick. Go to Browser, look on Google for "APPNAME android
>   market", click on the Google link and select "Open with Market".
>   However, paid apps still cannot be bought. But you can get the free
>   apps (some of them don't appear because they have an in-app payment
>   system).

There are [alternate market enabler apps](https://market.android.com/search?q=market%20enabler&c=apps) that might work, like this one:

https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler

It can be downloaded [directly](http://code.google.com/p/market-enabler/downloads/list) in case you can't get it through the market.

If that doesn't work, you could try different versions of the Android Market, starting with the latest, like Matthew Read suggested.  You could also try older versions of the Market Enabler app itself.  You'll have to Google around for those.

If none of that works, you could always contact the developer:

https://plus.google.com/110853353138524936530